# Сохранить изображение без X на Linux

Tags: python, linux, opencv, matplotlib

Linux server; Без иксов.
Необходимо сохранить гистограмму в отдельный файл без вывода на экран соответственно.

Нашел такой пример кода:

```
img = cv2.imread('home.bmp',0)
plt.hist(img.ravel(),256,[0,256])
```

При запуске ругается:

```
no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Как сохранить гистограмму в файл?  Перепробовал разные варианты с интернета, пробовал через matplotlib, но также не работает...
Пытался записать вариант, типа:

```
plt.savefig('histogram.jpg')
```

Comment: Не проще использовать PIL и попиксельно составлять гистограмму?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matplotlib поумолчанию выбирает Xwindows.

Решение:

```
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```